# How to split CSV into 12 csv's. 1 for each month

Tags: r, csv

I have a csv with several data points by month. I would like to split it into 12 different csv's, one for each month. Any suggestions as to how i can do this in R?

Comment: any sample code? You can 1.read the csv file into dataframe 2. subsets the dataframe by month to a new dataframe 3. write each new dataframe into a csv.

Comment: `?split` - `split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl)` for instance.

Comment: @addicted thats what i thought to do but i am not sure how to do it. Can you provide code to subset the dataframe by month.

Comment: @thelatemail can you provide more detail. i am not sure what i am doing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was thinking of using subset for each and every month but @thelatemail has provide better idea to split.

Let me just wrap it up in a code:

```
# 1. read csv
df <- read.csv("your_file_to_read.csv", header=TRUE)

# 2. split dataframe into multiple dataframe based on month
splitdf <- split(df, df$Month)

# 3. individually write them into csv
for(i in 1:length(splitdf))
{
    filename <- paste0("filemonth", i, ".csv")
    write.csv(splitdf[[i]], filename)
}
```

Comment: addicted and @thelatemail. This worked perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Patrick kindly credit @thelatemail too for `split` function idea.

Comment: Yes @thelatemail , my previous comment implied credit and thanks to both of you. unfortunately since i just started out my reputation is still below 15 so i can't vote up either of you. :(